# Prdct is a pointer pointing to address of struct variable item. Why r we using & operator again? It's already an address

Tags: c, pointers, structure

```
append(&item);  //function call

void append(struct invent_record *prdct)
{
  printf("Enter number");
  scanf("%d",&prdct->number);
}
```

Comment: `prdct` is a pointer, but `prdct->number` is not.  `&prdct->number` is taking the address of the `number` member of the struct.

Answer (score 2):

In the expression `&prdct->number`, the address-of operator is applied to `prdct->number`, since the `&` operator has lower precedence than the `->` operator.

So `prdct->number` dereferences `prdct` and gives you the `number` member of the struct.  Then the `&` operator takes the address of that member.

Answer (score 1):

`prdct` is a pointer, but `prdct->number` is not. `&prdct->number` is the address of the `number` member of the struct.